# Cassandra 3.x - Adding 3 nodes to a 6 node cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am looking to add 3 nodes to an existing 6 nodes cassandra cluster, but I'm a bit confused on how best to do this due to the token assignments.

Currently, the existing 6 node cluster is not using vNodes (this can't be changed) and is using RandomPartitioner and so the current tokens were added as per the token generator.  The issue is that adding 3 nodes to a 6 node cluster means that the recalculated tokens would put the new node 7 with the same token as the current node 5.

What is the best practice here?  Should I do a nodetool move on the existing nodes to add in the recalculated tokens, THEN bootstrap the new nodes with the correct config and tokens.  Or do I add the new nodes with no token, and once bootstrapped, then nodetool move across all the nodes adding in the newly calculated tokens, starting from the second node (as first node is always 0 with RandomPartitioner).

I've done a lot of reading, but can't seem to find a scenario that covers this eventuality.  And I can't add more than 3 nodes, long story...

Any help greatly received!

Comment: Just a questions: have you taken into account [migrating to vnodes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configVnodesProduction.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate the tokens for you whole cluster and assign the new tokens to the existing nodes. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddRplSingleTokenNodes.html). Since you are recalculating for the whole cluster, you should not have the issues that you are talking about.

I think that the best solution would be to [add a new DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCSingleTokenNodes.html) where you would use vnodes and Murmur3. After the data is replicated and you have moved all your clients to the new DC, you would [decommission the old DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately migrating to a new dc is not possible due to many factors I won’t bore you with.  As long as I can add the recalculated tokens to the existing nodes first, then add the new nodes with the correct tokens for the newly calculated 9 node cluster, then that’s perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: I found the link you posted, but this says to add the new nodes first which with my newly calculated tokens I cannot do without a token clash.  An afternoon searching for someone who had encountered this in a production system was fruitless. Either they don’t exist or they died from stress. 

Comment: I might be missing something, so please correct me if I'm wrong. I found this [link](https://petewarden.com/2011/07/20/cassandra-initial-tokens-table/). You have six nodes so your tokens should be the ones for six nodes. You are moving to nine, so according to the instructions you would change your existing initial_token value to match the ones for nine nodes. Then add your new nodes with the remaining initial tokens. After bootstrap, you would do a move (on the first six nodes, one node at a time) and then cleanup on the whole cluster (one node at a time).

Comment: Hi, ok I think I probably forgot some important info.  We are using RandomPartitioner, and not murmur3partitioner and so my token rages are like this: 0
28356863910078205288614550619314017621
56713727820156410577229101238628035242
85070591730234615865843651857942052863
113427455640312821154458202477256070484
141784319550391026443072753096570088105

Comment: With 9 nodes it will be like this: 0
18904575940052136859076367079542678414
37809151880104273718152734159085356828
56713727820156410577229101238628035242
75618303760208547436305468318170713656
94522879700260684295381835397713392070
113427455640312821154458202477256070484  <-- Token clashes with existing Node 5
132332031580364958013534569556798748898
151236607520417094872610936636341427312

Comment: I cannot change the partitioner, nor can I add a DC.  The existing parameters must stay the same.  So, in the link I cannot change the existing tokens in the yaml and then bootstrap the new nodes in using the newly generated token for the 9 node ring as this then clashes with existing node 5.  This is where I need the advice how to go about adding these nodes within my existing setup.  I cannot change the partitioners or move it to another DC first due to many factors, I need to complete this in the existing framework.

Comment: Have you consider using an offset when adding the new nodes? basically, in the new setup node1 will start with 100 instead of 0, node2 will have 18904575940052136859076367079542678514 and so on. The last node in the cluster (node9) will be responsible for the wrapping range covering all values higher than 151236607520417094872610936636341427312 plus from 0 to 99.

Comment: This leads me to a different question then, if adding an offset is an option then why not just move the existing nodes to the new tokens, then add the new nodes thus this eliminates the issue.  Is this possible to do, or must the new nodes be added first, before the tokens are moved?!

Comment: I think it can be done before adding the new nodes. Here is an article that explains [this](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/balancing-your-cassandra-cluster). I am also advising you to try this on a test system several times before applying it into production.

Comment: We did this in a production system and it worked fine. Moved the existing nodes to their new tokens one by one, and then bootstrapped the new nodes in one by one ensuring they fully joined the cluster first. Percentage owns is now correct for 9 nodes with the replication factor we are using.  Basically, this is pretty robust, and works well.

Comment: @TooHardBasket do you think is possible to share your steps and experience?